react-native-gifted-chat message rendering order issue
I am using react-native-gifted-chat to render messages. Every thing is working fine. However, there is this weird issue where the messages are not displaying in alternate order as can be seen in the attached image. Each new message appears on top of the previous bubble instead of in alternate order as it should in the chat app. I have tried changing the sorting method but nothing is working. Used new Date as well as Date.parse() to sort the messages based on Date. Nothing is working. It has been 2 days I am trying to resolve this bug. Documentation is not helpful as well.
Here is my code:
import React, { useState, useCallback, useRef } from 'react';
import { useFocusEffect } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { View, Text, Image, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { widthPercentageToDP as wp, heightPercentageToDP as hp } from 'react-native-responsive-screen';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { GiftedChat, Bubble } from 'react-native-gifted-chat';
import { AntDesign } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import socket from '../utilityFunctions/socket';

const backArrow = require('../../assets/images/backArrow.png');
const avatar = require('../../assets/images/avatar.png');

const ChatScreen = ({ navigation, route }) => {

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useFocusEffect(
    useCallback(() => {
      const handleTyping = (data) => {
        const status = data.status;
        if (status === true) {
          setIsTyping(true);
        } else {
          setIsTyping(false);
        }
      };
      const handleMessageReceived = (data) => {
        const sentMessage = data;
        setMessages((previousMessages) => {
          const updatedMessages = GiftedChat.append(previousMessages, sentMessage);
          return updatedMessages.sort((a, b) => Date.parse(b.createdAt) - Date.parse(a.createdAt));
        });
      };
      socket.on('typing', handleTyping);
      socket.on('messageReceivedInside', handleMessageReceived);
      return () => {
        socket.off('typing', handleTyping);
        socket.on('messageReceivedInside', handleMessageReceived);
      };
    }, [])
  );

  // current user who is logged in
  const senderID = useSelector((state) => state.user._id);
  const senderName = useSelector((state) => state.user.name);

  // user whose chat the current user has currently opened
  const recipientID = route.params.item._id;
  const recipientName = route.params.item.name;

  // users who are currently online
  const connectedUsers = useSelector((state) => state.connectedUsers);
  const chats = useSelector((state) => state.user.chats);

  const giftedChatRef = useRef(null); // for scrolling to bottom
  const [typing, setIsTyping] = useState(false); // if recipient is typing or not

  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]); // list of messages with the recipient

  let typingTimer;

  const onSend = useCallback((sentMessage = []) => {
    setMessages((previousMessages) => {
      const updatedMessages = GiftedChat.append(previousMessages, sentMessage);
      return updatedMessages.sort((a, b) => Date.parse(b.createdAt) - Date.parse(a.createdAt));
    });
    socket.emit('messageSendInside', { recipientID, sentMessage });
    if (giftedChatRef.current) {
      giftedChatRef.current._listRef._scrollRef.scrollToEnd();
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>

      <View style={styles.header}>
        <View 
          onStartShouldSetResponder={() => true}
          onResponderRelease={() => navigation.goBack()}
          style={styles.backArrowContainer}
        >
          <Image source={backArrow} style={styles.backArrow} />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.recipientInfoContainer}>
          <Image
            style={styles.avatar}
            source={avatar}
          />
          <View style={styles.recipientInfoContainerInner}>
            <Text style={styles.recipientName}> { recipientName } </Text>
            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
              {connectedUsers.some(user => user.userID === recipientID) && (
                <Text style={styles.activeNow}> Active now </Text>
              )}
              {typing && (
                <Text style={[styles.activeNow, { fontStyle: 'italic' }]}> (Typing...) </Text>
              )}
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.deleteButtonContainer}>
          <AntDesign name="delete" size={wp(6)} color={'#000E08'} />
        </View>
      </View>

      <View style={styles.giftedChat}>
        <GiftedChat
          messageContainerRef={giftedChatRef}
          messages={messages}
          // messages={
          //   messages.sort((a, b) => Date.parse(b.createdAt) - Date.parse(a.createdAt))
          // }
          onSend={sentMessage => onSend(sentMessage)}
          user={{
            _id: senderID,
            name: senderName
          }}
          inverted={false}
          alignTop={true}
          scrollToBottom={true}
          keyboardShouldPersistTaps="never"
          onInputTextChanged={(text) => {
            if (text.length > 0) {
              clearTimeout(typingTimer);
              socket.emit('typing', { recipientID, status: true });
              typingTimer = setTimeout(() => {
                  socket.emit('typing', { recipientID, status: false });
              }, 2000);
            }
          }}
          renderBubble={(props) => (
            <Bubble
              {...props}
              wrapperStyle={{
                right: {
                  backgroundColor: '#20A090', // sent bubble
                },
                left: {
                  backgroundColor: '#F2F7FB', // received bubble
                }
              }}
              textStyle={{
                // sent bubble
                right: {
                  color: '#FFFFFF',
                  fontFamily: 'CircularStd-Book',
                },
                // received bubble
                left: {
                  color: '#000E08',
                  fontFamily: 'Arial',
                },
              }}
            />
          )}
          renderTicks={(props) => {
              return (
                <Text
                  style={{
                    color: props.user._id == senderID ? '#FFFFFF' : '#000E08'
                  }}
                >
                  ✓
                </Text>
              );
            }
          }
        />
      </View>

    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },

  header: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
    paddingTop: wp(5)
  },
  backArrowContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  backArrow: {
    height: hp(4),
    resizeMode: 'contain',
    aspectRatio: 1,
  },
  recipientInfoContainer: {
    flex: 3,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start'
  },
  avatar: {
    width: wp(14),
    resizeMode: 'contain',
    aspectRatio: 1,
  },
  recipientInfoContainerInner: {
    marginLeft: wp(2),
  },
  recipientName: {
    fontSize: wp(4.5),
    fontFamily: 'Caros-Medium',
    color: '#000E08',
  },
  activeNow: {
    fontSize: wp(3),
    fontFamily: 'Caros-Medium',
    color: '#797C7B',
    marginLeft: wp(0.5),
    marginTop: wp(0.3)
  },
  deleteButtonContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },

  giftedChat: {
    flex: 8,
  },
});

export default ChatScreen;


Here is the image:
Message rendering order issue
Please let me know how to fix this.
So far as already mentioned, I changed sorting order using new Date() as well as Date.parse() nothing is working. Inverted is already set to false so that is not an issue as well.
